# Check my Kernel for SELinux Support

Tags: kernel, selinux

I want to know if the kernel i am running has support for SELinux. What commands would i use to check this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a 2.6 or later kernel, it is available. To know for sure, you have to look at the configuration for your kernel, look for the `CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_...` configuration options (kernel configuration is probably a file `/boot/config...`).

If it is a distribution kernel, it is most probably enabled.

Comment: Running a kernel that was compile by someone else so the version won't matter to me, still might be disabled. I just check the config file in boot and it showed it as disabled ty : )

Comment: `cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip > running.config` makes a copy of running config then i just did a search on it `grep -i selinux /root/running.config`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure if you are running a 2.6 kernel, you have it.  I use sestatus to check if SELinux is on or not.  If the output of `uname -r` shows a 2.6.something kernel you probably have selinux support.  Sestatus will show you if it is enabled or not.